# Python list comprehension not assigned to new array

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I'm new to python and I want to parse some data in class constructor. The input is a string with hex delimiters:

`b'\x01\x02A610088906\x03\x02R1138\x03\x02C\x03\x02B610089002\x03\x02SG20L71800\x03\x02MGFS4470\x03\x02m\x03\x02I47\x03\x04'`

I then want to split this string, and for each split I want to decode the result to utf-8 to discard the other characters that I'm not interested in:

```py
data = b'\x01\x02A610088906\x03\x02R1138\x03\x02C\x03\x02B610089002\x03\x02SG20L71800\x03\x02MGFS4470\x03\x02m\x03\x02I47\x03\x04'
frames = data.split(b'\x02')
utf_frames = [frame.decode('utf-8') for frame in frames]
print(utf_frames)
# Prints:
# ['\x01', 'A610088906\x03', 'R1138\x03', 'C\x03', 'B610089002\x03', 'SG20L71800\x03', 'MGFS4470\x03', 'm\x03', 'I47\x03\x04']
```

If I instead write my list comprehension like this I see the decoded values printed out:

```py
[print(frame.decode('utf-8')) for frame in frames]

A610088906
R1138
C
B610089002
SG20L71800
MGFS4470
m
I47
```

I am using version 3.8.5.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

For clarity, this is what I want to achieve (but I don't want to decode all entries each time I have to find one frame)

```
data = b'\x01\x02A610088906\x03\x02R1138\x03\x02C\x03\x02B610089002\x03\x02SG20L71800\x03\x02MGFS4470\x03\x02m\x03\x02I47\x03\x04'
frame_identifier = 'M'
frame = [frame for frame in data.split(b'\x02') if frame.decode('utf-8').startswith(frame_identifier)][0].decode('utf-8')[1:]
print(frame)
# GFS4470
```

**Solution**

Thanks to the answers I found the dangling `\x03` which wasn't visible since I decoded to a utf-8 string. This now works:

```py
frame_identifier = 'M'
data = b'\x01\x02A610088906\x03\x02R1138\x03\x02C\x03\x02B610089002\x03\x02SG20L71800\x03\x02MGFS4470\x03\x02m\x03\x02I47\x03\x04'
utf_frames = [frame.decode('utf-8') for frame in data.split(b'\x02')]
frame = [frame for frame in self.utf_frames if frame.startswith(frame_identifier)][0][1:-1]
print(type(frame), frame, str(frame), repr(frame))
# <class 'str'> GFS4470 GFS4470 'GFS4470'
```

Comment: Are using linux?

Comment: Yes, Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: `/xo3` is `^c` character; the `ctrl + c`.

Comment: How come all frames are printed when I don't assign to a list? Shouldn't `\x03` causes issues there too?

Comment: Yeah that's the thing I can't seem to reproduce this as i get a blank box character in linux and windows too; which is expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's go back to your first coding example and modify it slightly to see what is going on:

```
data = b'\x01\x02A610088906\x03\x02R1138\x03\x02C\x03\x02B610089002\x03\x02SG20L71800\x03\x02MGFS4470\x03\x02m\x03\x02I47\x03\x04'
frames = data.split(b'\x02')
utf_frames = [frame.decode('utf-8') for frame in frames]
print(utf_frames)
for f in utf_frames:
    print(type(f), f, str(f), repr(f))
```

Prints:

```
['\x01', 'A610088906\x03', 'R1138\x03', 'C\x03', 'B610089002\x03', 'SG20L71800\x03', 'MGFS4470\x03', 'm\x03', 'I47\x03\x04']
<class 'str'>   '\x01'
<class 'str'> A610088906 A610088906 'A610088906\x03'
<class 'str'> R1138 R1138 'R1138\x03'
<class 'str'> C C 'C\x03'
<class 'str'> B610089002 B610089002 'B610089002\x03'
<class 'str'> SG20L71800 SG20L71800 'SG20L71800\x03'
<class 'str'> MGFS4470 MGFS4470 'MGFS4470\x03'
<class 'str'> m m 'm\x03'
<class 'str'> I47 I47 'I47\x03\x04'
```

So when you print a list of the decoded frames rather each one individually, Python chooses to call the `repr` method on each list element rather than the `str` method.

Comment: Thank you so much, this explains a lot in such a nice way.

Answer (score 1):

Python doesn't `print` contents of lists, only just `print` its structure. In case of using list comprehension, python `print` each element of a list. So control characters didn't appear in console.

Comment: Thanks! I marked the other as an answer because I wouldn't have understood this without an example